# How do you write a matrix to a text file?

Tags: r

I want to create a text file that contains my matrix but when I do so, **the zeroes in the decimal place are removed from the text file.** The **spacing** also does not look like the matrix. My matrix contains **characters and numbers.**

I have tried using the command
`format.data.frame(pdb, drop0trailing=FALSE))`
in `write.table()` but it shows me an error.

Here, pdb is a data frame that looks like this:

```
1        HETATM    Hg -1.587  1.030  4.699
2        HETATM     S -3.710 -0.367  2.815
3        HETATM     O -3.504 -0.700  1.425
4        HETATM     O -3.195 -1.292  3.794
5        HETATM     N -2.987  1.040  3.206
6        HETATM     N -4.033  2.237  1.479
7        HETATM     N -2.290  3.179  2.822
8        HETATM     N -9.515  0.232  3.780
9        HETATM     H -9.856  0.865  4.398
10       HETATM     H -9.995 -0.508  3.440
11       HETATM     C -3.120  2.191  2.445
12       HETATM     C -4.111  3.404  0.814
13       HETATM     H -4.731  3.479  0.098
14       HETATM     C -3.335  4.492  1.130
15       HETATM     H -3.421  5.316  0.665
16       HETATM     C -2.425  4.332  2.152
17       HETATM     H -1.871  5.067  2.391
18       HETATM     C -5.435 -0.141  3.075
19       HETATM     C -6.322 -0.952  2.385
20       HETATM     H -6.001 -1.575  1.744
21       HETATM     C -7.683 -0.847  2.635
22       HETATM     H -8.295 -1.406  2.169
23       HETATM     C -8.159  0.068  3.562
24       HETATM     C -7.254  0.882  4.254
25       HETATM     H -7.574  1.515  4.885
26       HETATM     C -5.901  0.766  4.021
27       HETATM     H -5.287  1.306  4.504
28       HETATM     O  0.302  0.623  2.794
29       HETATM     N  1.028 -1.026  1.408
30       HETATM     C  0.097 -0.339  2.054
31       HETATM     H -0.804 -0.614  1.936
32       HETATM     C  2.443 -0.700  1.575
33       HETATM     H  2.550 -0.097  2.340
34       HETATM     H  2.776 -0.263  0.763
35       HETATM     H  2.952 -1.523  1.735
36       HETATM     C  0.673 -2.117  0.521
37       HETATM     H  1.058 -2.952  0.861
38       HETATM     H  1.026 -1.937 -0.376
39       HETATM     H -0.302 -2.198  0.477
```

This is my code:

```
pdb = cbind.data.frame(atom_keyword, atoms, orth)
write.table(pdb, file = "/home/ibab/Bioinfo/mypdb.txt", sep = "   ", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, format.data.frame(pdb, drop0trailing=FALSE))
```

where `orth` is a matrix that contains x, y, z coordinates in decimal form. 
I expect the text file to look exactly like the data frame I have pasted above but instead it looks something like this:

```
HETATM   Hg   -1.59   1.03   4.7
HETATM   S   -3.71   -0.367   2.81
HETATM   O   -3.5   -0.7   1.42
HETATM   O   -3.19   -1.29   3.79
```

When I use `drop0trailing`, I get an error message as follows:

```
Error in ifelse(append, "a", "w") : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

Comment: Trying using the tab character "\t" instead of spaces for the separator.   This should provide better (not perfect) results.  Values in each column will also need to be approximately the same length.

Comment: can you try `write.table(pdb, file = "/home/ibab/Bioinfo/mypdb.txt", sep = "\t", dec = ".",  quote = FALSE)`